# Iterating through a matrix with same vector in C

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix, vector

I have got two matrices which the same amount of rows, but different amount of columns. To make my explanation easy to understand, let us call the matrices `a` and `b`.

Matrix a has 256 columns and 600 rows

Matrix b has 55 columns and 600 rows

What I am trying to achieve is to compute a matrix of correlation coefficients between the columns of the two input matrices, resulting in one matrix of dimension 256 columns and 55 rows.

I want to calculate Pearson correlation coefficient, which has the following equation:

[image]

My suggestion for the solution is to implement two nested for loops:

```
int x[600]; 
int y[600];

for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){
          for (int j= 0; j<600; j++ ) {
               x[j] = matrixA[j][i];
          }

          for (int k = 0; k < 55; ++k){
             for (int j= 0; j<600; j++ ) {
                  y[j] = matrixB[j][k];
             }
            }
    }
```

I am not sure whether this is the right way to do it. How can I achieve it otherwise?

Comment: What do you need to do with these elements?

Comment: I want to calculate the correlation coefficient

Comment: `y[i]` is getting overwritten each time around the `k` loop.

Comment: @Bab please add the necessary information about correlation coefficient

Comment: Correlation coefficient of what with what? and what result size?

Comment: x[j] and y[i] are of no use for storing as they are getting overwritten

Comment: You are using `i` in both the outer and inner loops, although that might be due to incorrect nesting of the loops (it's hard to tell from the bad indentation!). Also, your outer `i` loop has `++l` instead of `++i`. Also, your `j` loop has `i++` instead of `j++`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Correlation coeffiecient of matrix a with matrix b columnwise

Comment: @IanAbbott: My bad, I missed that. It's corrected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so assuming you want to store the results in c, with dims 256, 50, do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < 55; ++j)
    {
        c[i][j] = compute_correlation(matrixA, i, matrixB, j);
    }
```

with `compute_correlation` a simple for loop that will compute the value according to the formal:

```
double compute_correlation(double matrixA[600][256], i, double matrixB[600][55], j)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < 600; ++k)
    {
      // Compute means of both rows
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 600; ++k)
    {
      // Compute numerator
      // Compute denominator
    }
    return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't matrixA and B be: matrixA[600][256] and matrixB[600][55] as I have 600 rows?

Comment: Oh yes indeed... But it's definitely bad for performance, 600 should be the fastest dimension, not the slowest.

Comment: So I just to be sure that I understand it correctly: First you iterate through one column of matrixA a at a time while iterating through all columns of matrixB. Then you iterate through all rows and compute the means of both rows. Then you iterate again through all rows and compute the numerator and denominator. Lastly you calculate the r. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You end up with a matrix of correlations, so that's why you need the first two loops, and then the last loops are inside the correlation function just to factor out this specific code.

Comment: The mean should be computed outside the for loop, right? In the for loop I compute the sums of both rows, and outside the for loop I divide by 600

Comment: There is no division by 600 in the formula. In `compute_correlation`, first compute the mean of `x` and `y`, so the columns you want to correlate, then compute the three sums.

Comment: But the mean is computed by sum / n, and n is 600 as each column has 600 rows.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, forgot about that division :p Yes, of course, it has to be done after the loop.

Comment: The c matrix a temporary matrix right?

Comment: c is your result matrix.